# How to run spotbugs from command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, spotbugs

There is a need of executing spotbugs from command line, i have got some information from the google search however i'm running into some problems. Somebody please help me providing an example to get it work. I'm running spotbugs however the usage says i need to use findbugs and i'm confused.

I'm using : **SPOTBUGS version 4.7.2**

Command that im using : java -jar spotbugs.jar -textui -effort:default -sortByClass=/tmp/sportbugs.txt  -low -html=/tmp/sbugs.html -sourcepath /tmp/Program

**ERROR BELOW:**

```
    Unexpected problem occured during version sanity check
    Reported exception:
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
    org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider.getRequestedApiVersion()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.versionSanityCheck(LoggerFactory.java:297)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:141)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:421)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:407)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:356)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:382)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.CheckBcel.<clinit>(CheckBcel.java:40)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.LaunchAppropriateUI.launch(LaunchAppropriateUI.java:99)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.LaunchAppropriateUI.main(LaunchAppropriateUI.java:198)
    Sep 07, 2022 11:11:22 AM edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs processCommandLine
    WARNING: No files to be analyzed
    Sep 07, 2022 11:11:22 AM edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs showSynopsis
    WARNING: Usage: findbugs [general options] -textui [command line options...] 
    [jar/zip/class files, directories...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply forgot to tell SpotBugs where your class files are: With "-sourcepath /tmp/Program" in your command you tell SpotBugs where your source files are, but SpotBugs operates on Java bytecode. So you have to consider "[jar/zip/class files, directories...]", see last line of the error message.

FindBugs: Don't get lead up the garden path. FindBugs is the predecessor of SpotBugs and there is much code of FindBugs in the SpotBugs project left. You don't need FindBugs when you have SpotBugs...

Answer (score 0):

Run the following ps script which downloads spotbugs, dearchives it and executes it through textui

```
$url = "https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/releases/download/4.7.3/spotbugs-4.7.3.zip"
Invoke-WebRequest -URI $url -OutFile "spotbugs-4.7.3.zip"
Expand-Archive "spotbugs-4.7.3.zip"
.\spotbugs-4.7.3\spotbugs-4.7.3\bin\spotbugs.bat -textui -maxHeap 2000 -jvmArgs "-XX:+UseParallelGC" -effort:min -high -progress "myJar.jar"
```